# Change in dataframe in R dates of the form S.10 to 2019/09/10

Tags: r, dataframe, date, date-conversion

I am relatively new to R and I would like to convert the dates, which are currently in the form of S.10, to dates of the form 2019/09/10.

Thank you very much for all your help in advance!

Comment: I imagine the S stands for September in this format. How do you differentiate May and March or June, July and January or April and August?

Comment: In the data  J stands for January, J* for June and J** stands for July.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `gsubfn`:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("J.1", "F.14", "M.12", "A.5", "M*.22", "J*.21", "J**.2", "A*.18", "S.10", "O.12", "N.8", "D.31"))

library(gsubfn)

df$Date <- gsubfn("J.|F.|M.|A.|M\\*.|J\\*.|J\\*\\*.|A\\*.|S.|O.|N.|D.", 
                  list("J." = "1 ", 
                       "F." = "2 ", 
                       "M." = "3 ", 
                       "A." = "4 ", 
                       "M*." = "5 ", 
                       "J*." = "6 ",
                       "J**." = "7 ", 
                       "A*." = "8 ", 
                       "S." = "9 ", 
                       "O." = "10 ", 
                       "N." = "11 ", 
                       "D." = "12 "),
                  df$Date)

df$Date <- as.Date(paste(2019, df$Date), format = "%Y %m %d")
```

Which givs the following output:

```
> df
         Date
1  2019-01-01
2  2019-02-14
3  2019-03-12
4  2019-04-05
5  2019-05-22
6  2019-06-21
7  2019-07-02
8  2019-08-18
9  2019-09-10
10 2019-10-12
11 2019-11-08
12 2019-12-31
```